# How do I make a reusable method for two data classes in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am working my way through the TDD Explained book in order to learn Kotlin. At the moment I have the following code:

```
data class Dollar (private val amount: Int) {
    fun times(multiplier: Int) = Dollar(amount = this.amount * multiplier)
}

data class Franc (private val amount: Int) {
    fun times(multiplier: Int) = Franc(amount = this.amount * multiplier)
}
```

As you can see, multiplying a dollar results in a dollar and same goes for a Franc, this is the logic I want. However I would like to try and make a reusable function to reduce the duplicate logic. I am not sure if I am on the correct path, but I have come up with this:

```
data class Dollar (val amount: Int)
data class Franc (val amount: Int)

fun Dollar.times(multiplier: Int) = Dollar(amount = this.amount * multiplier)
fun Franc.times(multiplier: Int) = Franc(amount = this.amount * multiplier)
```

I am not sure if this is on the correct track or not.

How could I reuse this logic in an idiomatic Kotlin way?

These are the current tests which are currently passing

```
    @Test
fun testDollarMultiplication() {
    val five = Dollar(5)
    assertEquals( Dollar(10), five.times(2))
    assertEquals( Dollar(15), five.times(3))
}

@Test
fun testFrancMultiplication() {
    val five = Franc(5)
    assertEquals( Franc(10), five.times(2))
    assertEquals( Franc(15), five.times(3))
}

@Test
fun testEquality() {
    assertTrue(Dollar(5).equals(Dollar(5)))
    assertFalse(Dollar(5).equals(Dollar(10)))
    assertTrue(Franc(5).equals(Franc(5)))
    assertFalse(Franc(5).equals(Franc(10)))
    assertFalse(Dollar(5).equals("hi"))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with a generic reusable function for this, is that it will need to create a new instance of your money-type, without knowing which concrete type to construct. A workaround to this could be to pass in a `construct`-function as a parameter, but that would make quite an ugly API if you had to call it like this: `fiveDollar.times(5, { Dollar(it) })`.

One solution to this issue is to create an interface `Money`, which `Dollar` and `Franc` implement. The interface needs to know its "self"-type in order for `times` to return the correct currency. Kotlin doesn't support self-types, but it supports recursive type parameters, which can emulate self-types to some extent.

The interface needs to know how to construct an instance of the implementing type, so it needs to define a "construct" function. To write the `times`-function in it, you also need to give it access to the `amount` (so the property can't be private).

Something like this:

```kotlin
interface Money<T : Money<T>> {
    val amount: Int
    fun construct(amount: Int): T
    
    fun times(multiplier: Int): T = construct(amount * multiplier)
}

data class Dollar(override val amount: Int) : Money<Dollar> {
    override fun construct(amount: Int) = Dollar(amount)
}

data class Franc(override val amount: Int) : Money<Franc> {
    override fun construct(amount: Int) = Franc(amount)
}
```

You could also keep the `amount`-property private, and hide the construct function by using an abstract class instead and pass them as values to its constructor. That would look like this:

```kotlin
abstract class Money<T : Money<T>>(private val amount: Int, private val construct: (Int) -> T) {
    fun times(multiplier: Int): T = construct(amount * multiplier)
}

data class Dollar(private val amount: Int) : Money<Dollar>(amount, ::Dollar)
data class Franc(private val amount: Int) : Money<Franc>(amount, ::Franc)
```

Edit:

Another clean and flexible solution is to model the currency as a sealed interface with data objects extending it. Then use it as a type parameter on the `Money`-type. Like this:

```kotlin
sealed interface Currency {
    operator fun invoke(amount: Int): Money<out Currency>
}

data object Dollar : Currency {
    override operator fun invoke(amount: Int) = Money(amount, this)
}

data object Franc : Currency {
    override operator fun invoke(amount: Int) = Money(amount, this)
}

data class Money<T : Currency>(val amount: Int, val currency: T) {
    fun times(multiplier: Int) = Money(amount * multiplier, currency)
}
```

Note the `out`-variance on the invoke-function, which allows the override in `Dollar` and `Franc` to return a `Money<Dollar>`/`Money<Franc>` instead of `Money<Currency>`.

Comment: I have noticed that the book eventually introduces a currency string to the constructor. This would make things easier.

The solution above is great given the constraints from the question.

Comment: @Daryn I was contemplating adding a solution like that to the answer too, but it got quite long :) Using strings would make you not get the same type guarantees though. You could used a sealed type hierarchy instead to retain it. See my edit for an example :)